# convert a line to a Node in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that takes a line as a `string` and converts it into a `Node`.

```
Node convertLineToNode(string line){
    char lineC[] = line;
    Node *n = new Node();
    n->lastname=strtok(lineC," ");
    n->name=strtok(lineC," ");
    n->ID=strtok(lineC," ");
 }
```

However it doesn't work properly. It expects the `string` line as `char` array. I couldn't convert it into `char` array. Is there any solutions for my problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C++ way would be this:

```
Node* convertLineToNode(std::string const & line)
{
   std::istringstream iss(line);
   Node *n = new Node();
   iss >> n->lastname
       >> n->name
       >> n->ID;
   return n;
}
```

consider returning a shared_pointer instead of a raw one

Comment: +1: I honestly would not have thought of that. I guess, the real C++-way though is to make `Node` have a constructor that takes the appropriate values for it's members. Or, to overload `operator>>` for `Node`. There are many options.

Comment: is there any library that i should include to use istringstream?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Normally, I'd define a >> operator for my struct and use `boost::lexical_cast`

Comment: @exculuber: `#include <sstream>`

Comment: when I call the function with suppliying argument with string i get this error: conversion from `std::ifstream' to non-scalar type `std::string' requested. How can I convert the string to std::string?

Comment: @exculuber: er... what ifstream? We haven't seen any ifstreams in your code so far. the STL string class is declared in std namespace. You must explicitly qualify that it is std::string, or write a using declaration `using std::string;` or a using-directive `using namespace std;`

Answer (score 0):

`string::c_str()` will return the C String representation.

However, instead of using c string libraries (strtok), I would consider rewriting your method to make use of the std::string methods, or even the boost regex library.

Comment: could you rewrite in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

thats probably because your `n->lastname` has a string data type. The `strtok` returns `char*` so make sure your data structures corresponds well with what the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

It could also work like this, if Nodes can be copied:

```
Node convert(string line) {
   Node n;
   n.lastname = "abc";
   return n;
 }
```

But Node will need to support copying:

```
Node n = convert("abc");
```

The copying can be implemented by copy constructor.